# Redraw table view cell without calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm going to asynchronously load an image and set it to the table view cell. The problem is that I use Auto-Layout for my cells, so I want table view to redraw the cell after setting the image.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300.0
```

In usual case I'd use `tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)`, but this calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, which calls my image downloading method again.

I tried to call `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()`, `cell.layoutIfNeeded()`, `cell.setNeedsLayout()`, nothing helped.

My questions is how to I redraw a table view cell without calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem here is the way you are downloading your image. You should do some bookkeeping in your code and keep track of which image is already downloading or has already been downloaded. Depending on that, you can decide if you should start a new download.
Do not try to hack around this, as this will cause you a lot of pain later (I know from experience). 
The best way is to have a data-object of some kind, and another object that does the downloading. Then whenever a download finishes, this object updates the correct dataobject for this image. Then this downloader should tell your dataSource that this data object was updated. In response, your dataSource can reload the indexPath for that dataobject. IN this way, your dataSource never has to worry about downloading, and can simply inspect the data-object and use it to set values on the cell. If there is an image downloaded, it will use it, otherwise no images (or some placeholder maybe).

For now, you can keep a dictionary property that contains an @(YES) or @(NO) as value for the URL or name or indexPath of the cell as key. However this method is naive, in that it won't be very maintainable or portable (to other viewControllers or sections of your app), and there is not easy conversion between indexPath and image. Remember that the tableViewCells can never be used as a source of data for using some logic: they are the terminal point where other logic you have will place data onto. This is because they are re-used and basically can not be trusted to be in a certain position ever. Base everything you do on indexPaths alone. (and use the tableview to get an indexPath for a cell).

So, for now you can do in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
NSString * imageURL = ....
NSNumber * downloading = self.imageDownloads[imageURL];
if (!downloading.boolValue)
{
    self.imageDownloads[imageURL] = @(YES);
    // start your download
}

- (void) imageDownloadedForURL: (NSString *) imageURL
{
    self.imageDownloads[imageURL] = @(YES); // this is redundant
    [self.tableView reloadRowAtIndexPaths: @[indexPathForThisImage]];
}
- (void) imageDownloadForULRFailed: (NSString *) imageURL
{
    self.imageDownloads[imageURL] = @(NO);
    // trigger a new download? (but be careful not to DDOS your server this way)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to redraw the cell if you're using an `UIImageView` to display the image, just set the image property when your image finishes download.

If you are drawing the image yourself on a custom `UIView` subclass, you can call the `setNeedDisplay` method on that view, which marks the view as dirty and will be redrawn at the next cycle.

However, the best approach would be to improve the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and to set a `downloading` flag in your model objects, and start the download only if that flag is not set.